# How can we use facebook login to authenticate to SharePoint

Tags: claims-based-auth, forms-authentication

I know SharePoint 2010 has claims based authentication. First off, is it possible to use facebook as the authentication mechanism in SharePoint 2010?

If it is possible what are the steps needed from an architectural level to accomplish this. For example.

How are credentials passed and received from facebook?

Where is the user store located in SharePoint?

What are the steps to build this kind of solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Watch this blog from Travis Nielsen: http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/nielsen_travis/pages/default.aspx

Comment: Wow! That is quite a series on Facebook integration!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in the Facebook Connect system, but here's how you wold do it in another case.

Check [here](http://stefvanhooijdonk.com/2010/08/19/writing-your-own-trusted-identity-provider-for-sp2010-1/) .

This is a good start.  It's fairly simple and really powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Shetab have some OpenID Membership providers available which you could try:

http://www.shetabtech.com/english/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is well explained tutorial how to achieve it:
http://ovaismehboob.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/configuring-facebook-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010/

EDIT:

and list of few options how to integrate FB or Skype into SP:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4534.sharepoint-integrate-skype-and-facebook-features.aspx